# one row for rec_id with the last change and total days | sql

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, presto, trino, amazon-athena

I have "customers" table with this data:

| cust_id | start_date | end_date | street_id | hood_id | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 569 | 1/1/2022 | 1/15/2022 | 12 | 17 | 16 |
| 569 | 1/19/2022 | 1/22/2022 | 9 | 85 | 15 |
| 569 | 1/25/2022 | 2/25/2022 | 14 | 65 | 19 |
| 241 | 3/13/2022 | 3/17/2022 | 3 | 6 | 19 |
| 241 | 3/19/2022 | 3/22/2022 | 5 | 8 | 35 |
| 241 | 3/25/2022 | 3/29/2022 | 5 | 8 | 488 |

I want to stay just with one raw per **cust_id** and also to stay with the **last changes** of street_id, hood_id, and city_id columns. also, I want to **create a new sum column** that brings me the "total_days" (end_date - start_date). its looks like this:

| cust_id | street_id | hood_id | city_id | total_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 569 | 14 | 65 | 19 | 48 |
| 241 | 5 | 8 | 488 | 11 |

if it will be in presto syntax it will be wonderful.

thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest row per customer with `row_number()`  and filtering, then do the date arithmetic:

```
select cust_id, street_id, hood_id, city_id,
    date_diff('day', start_date, end_date) as total_days
from (
    select c.*, row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by end_date desc) rn
    from customers c
) c
where rn = 1
```

Ah, and you seem to want the *overall* date difference per customer rather than that of the last row, so we can use more window functions:

```
select cust_id, street_id, hood_id, city_id, total_days
from (
    select c.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by end_date desc) rn,
        sum(date_diff('day', start_date, end_date)) over(partition by cust_id) as total_days
    from customers c
) c
where rn = 1
```

Comment: In addition, I need to do union to "customers_new" table with the "end_date_new" column and not "end_date" column. 
and I need to do HAVING total_days < 55 for all query.  
do you have any solution for this? thanks any way! 
@GMB

Answer (score 0):

Looks like job for `GROUP BY` combined with some [aggregation functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html) (especially very useful in such cases `max_by`) and dates handling (parsing dates and counting diff in days):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(cust_id, start_date, end_date, street_id, hood_id, city_id) as(
    values (569, '1/1/2022', '1/15/2022', 12,   17, 16),
    (569, '1/19/2022', '1/22/2022', 9,  85, 15),
    (569, '1/25/2022', '2/25/2022', 14, 65, 19),
    (241, '3/13/2022', '3/17/2022', 3,  6, 19),
    (241, '3/19/2022', '3/22/2022', 5,  8, 35),
    (241, '3/25/2022', '3/29/2022', 5,  8, 488)
)

-- query
select cust_id,
    max_by(street_id, end_date) street_id,
    max_by(hood_id, end_date) hood_id,
    max_by(city_id, end_date) city_id,
    sum(date_diff('day', date_parse(start_date, '%c/%e/%Y'), date_parse(end_date, '%c/%e/%Y'))) total_days
from dataset
group by cust_id;
```

Output:

| cust_id | street_id | hood_id | city_id | total_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 241 | 5 | 8 | 488 | 11 |
| 569 | 14 | 65 | 19 | 48 |